# PostgreSQL : could not write to file "pg_wal/xlogtemp no space left device due to autovacuum

Tags: postgresql

Recently, on my PostgreSQL logs, I found :

2021-09-30 08:33:37.242 CEST [4183904] PANIC:  could not write to file "pg_wal/xlogtemp.4183904": No space left on device
2021-09-30 08:33:37.242 CEST [4183904] CONTEXT:  writing block 413931 of relation base/238033/270693
2021-09-30 08:33:46.609 CEST [1376] LOG:  server process (PID 4183904) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2021-09-30 08:33:46.609 CEST [1376] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: autovacuum: VACUUM public.public_components_versions_files

My question is why the process autovacuum cause writing block of relation (index on table), knowing that autovacuum not reclaim space....
for information base/238033/270693 is an index for table public_components_versions_files, so autovacuum (public_components_versions_files) attempt to writing block for index (index on public_components_versions_files)

postrgesqL version 12.8

<I see on documentation : The standard form of VACUUM removes dead row versions in tables and indexes and marks the space available for future reuse. However, it will not return the space to the operating system, except in the special case where one or more pages at the end of a table become entirely free and an exclusive table lock can be easily obtained>

So perhaps, this autovacuum return the space to the operating system, because one or more pages at the end of a table become entirely free and an exclusive table lock can be easily obtained

Thank you in advance.

Cheers,

Adil

Comment: What you are seeing appears to have nothing to do with returning space to the operating system.  Trying to force them to be related when they are not makes no sense.

Comment: OK, why failed autovaccum process, try to writing block, that is the question, autovacuum removes dead row versions in tables and indexes and marks the space available for future reuse, this behaviour(writing temp blocks) is seen when Vacuum full

Comment: Removing dead tuples still needs to be recoverable, so still needs to generate WAL.  The PANIC message is quite clear, it can't write the WAL because "No space left on device".

Comment: thank you @jjanes for your support, you 're right, understood, vacuum also generate WAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VACUUM` writes to the table (it modifies it), but it does not extend the table. However, since all data modifications have to be logged in the Write Ahead Log, `VACUUM`'s modifications have to be logged as well.

PostgreSQL is running out of space writing the transaction log, not modifying the table.